# Calcular vector medio de una serie de filas cuyos campos contienen vectores en R

Tags: r

Tengo un archivo csv que tiene la sigueinte estructura como ejemplo mínimo:

```
ID       Variable       Vector
1         a              [0,0,0]
2         a              [1,2,3]
1         a              [1,1,2]
2         a              [1,2,3]
1         b              [0,0,0]
2         b              [1,1,1]
1         b              [0,0,1]
2         b              [3,5,7]
```

Me gustaría aprender la manera de calcular el vector medio para cada ID. Es decir, obtener un dataframe como el siguiente:

```
ID       Variable       Vector
1          a             [0.5,0.5,1]
2          a             [1,2,3]
1          b             [0,0,0.5]
2          b             [2,3,4]
```

No sé muy bien por dónde empezar porque parece que la estructura de datos entre corchetes es rara en R.

Comment: ¿Tienes un archivo físico con los datos que muestras, o ya tienes un `data.frame` de esta forma? ¿podrías agregar la estrucutra de los datos con `str(tu_data_frame)`?

Comment: @Patricio Moracho, muchas gracias, he conseguido una respuesta que acabo de pegar... estoy trabajando con R estos días y he olvidado muchas cosas, espero me puedas echar un cable !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una aproximación, a mi criterio más sencilla, sería hacer un `split` de la columna `Vector` en múltiples columnas, y sobre estas aplicar una agregación para calcular la media:

Datos:

```
read.table(text="ID       Variable       Vector
1         a              [0,0,0]
2         a              [1,2,3]
1         a              [1,1,2]
2         a              [1,2,3]
1         b              [0,0,0]
2         b              [1,1,1]
1         b              [0,0,1]
2         b              [3,5,7]
", header=TRUE) -> df
```

---

#### Con `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(Vector= gsub('\\]|\\[','', Vector)) %>% 
  separate(Vector, into = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), sep=",", convert=TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(ID, Variable) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("V1", "V2", "V3"), mean)
```

---

#### Con `R` base

```
m <- do.call('rbind', strsplit(gsub('\\]|\\[','', df$Vector),',',fixed=TRUE))
class(m) <- "numeric"
new_df <- cbind(df, as.data.frame(m))
aggregate(cbind(V1, V2, V3) ~ Variable + ID, new_df, mean)
```

Answer (score 2):

He investigado en otro foro y he encontrado una respuesta satusfacotria que comparto por si es útil a algún usuario hispanohablante que tenga este problema con esta estructura de datos. Primero agrupamos los datos y después operamos.

```
library(stringr)
out <- data %>%
          group_by(ID, Variable) %>%
          summarise(Vector = list((str_extract_all(Vector, "\\d+") %>%
                    map(as.numeric) %>% reduce(`+`))/n()), .groups = 'drop')
```